# i need to test an html page i made by a mobile connected through verizon

Tags: javascript, html, testing, mobile

i have this page

http://m.bsmitho.com/

and i need someone who's connected through a verizon mobile (mobile connection not wifi) to test my page and tell me if the verizon mobile logo appears ?

the code i have used :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
             if (response.org == "AS6541 Verizon Online LLC") {
             document.getElementById("verizon").style.display = "block";
                 }
          }, "jsonp");
     });

     </script>
```

please i need your help, soon.

thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a user testing website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
         if (response.org == "AS6541 Verizon Online LLC") {
         document.getElementById("verizon").style.display = "block";
             }
      }, "jsonp");
 });

 </script>
```